# Express JS Get URL from AJAX Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I am building an Express App and I need to store the user's URL from where their AJAX request was made. For example, if I have a website at www.example.com make an HTTP request to my Express App on Heroku, I want to get the www.example.com URL. I used this code below from another SO article and it is returning the host name of my Heroku app.

```
var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
```

Also tried this:

```
var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.hostname + req.originalUrl;
```

The get('host') and hostname are the parts that are rendering incorrectly. Again, I want to get the URL from where the HTTP request came from.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the Referrer

```
var fullUrl = req.get('Referrer');
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Do you know if this also works for "https" as well?

Comment: No problem. IIRC if your service is run over https you should get the referrer either way; if you are http and the requestor is https the referrer will  get scrubbed.